# Can animation in react native be paused and restarted?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
onAnimation(){

    var animation = Animated.timing(this.state.spin,{
        toValue:1,
        duration:4000,
        easing:Easing.linear
    });
    animation.start();
}


onPause(){
    this.state.spin.stopAnimation();
}
```

I am practicing animations in react native. As code shown above, the animation's velocity will becoming slower because 'the.state.spin' has changed but the animation time is still 4000ms.So I want to reset the state.But the 'the.state.spin' is a Animated.Value. I don't know how to restart the animation without slowing the animation velocity.

Can anyone help me or tell me the correct way to pause and restart the animation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Official Doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/animations.html#responding-to-the-current-animation-value) here

you can pass a `callback` to `stopAnimation` like:

`this.state.spin.stopAnimation(this.callback);`

then you can get the final value after stopping the `animation` in the `callback`. You can do whatever you want with the value, like adjust the `duration` to achieve the `restart` function.

Comment: the final value in the callback was always zero for me with useNativeDriver, I had to get the final value instead with a listener: `this.state.myAnim.addListener(({ value }) => this.myAnimValue = value);`

Comment: With `myAnim.interpolate(...)`, do you know how to make it work? It doesn't seem to update for me.

Comment: Okay I found my solution!! Make sure that the `new Animated.Value(0)` instantiation is done ONCE, or at least in a way that doesn't block the second `.start()`